# How to find a string in string and replace it?

Tags: c++, string, boost

I have a `std::string A` I need to find in it string `B` with content like `bla-bla-bla` and replace it with other string `C` like `abcdefg` and if `B` was not found just put `C` at the beginning of `A`.

How to do such thing?

Comment: it is use full when you have some ones url and you want to make it use  something like 'rtmp://' instead of 'http://' and ofcourse you newer know if 'http://'.)

Comment: Have you looked at string::replace and string::find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void replace_or_merge(std::string &a, const std::string &b, const std::string &c)
{
  const std::string::size_type pos_b_in_a = a.find(b);
  if(pos_b_in_a == std::string::npos) {
    a.insert(0, c);
  }
  else {
    a.replace(pos_b_in_a, b.length(), c);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 / sounds logic, but better to pass b and c as `const std::string&`

Answer (score 2):

```
A.replace(str.find(B), B.length(), C);
```

You might want to add error checking ;-)